# BlueSky Statistics - Changing the Numerical Stas Analysis syntax to drop the n & NAs

Tags: r, rgui

When the supplied Numerical Stats Analysis is run the output adds in n & NA's by default. 
The syntax is:

```
## [Numerical Statistical Analysis]
BSky_Dataset_Overview = data.frame(Dataset = c("Dataset2"),Variables = length(names(Dataset2)),Observations = nrow(Dataset2))

BSky_Numerical_Statistics_Analysis = BSkySummaryStats(datasetColumnObjects = list(fc1 = Dataset2$fc1,fc2 = Dataset2$fc2,fc3 = Dataset2$fc3),groupByColumnObjects = list(SalesArea = Dataset2$SalesArea),statFunctionList = c(min=FALSE,max=FALSE,mean=TRUE,median=FALSE,sum=FALSE,sd=FALSE,stderror=FALSE,iqr=FALSE,quantiles=FALSE),datasetName="Dataset2" )

BSkyFormat(BSky_Dataset_Overview,singleTableOutputHeader=c("Dataset Overview"))
BSkyFormat(BSky_Numerical_Statistics_Analysis,singleTableOutputHeader=c("Numerical Statistical Analysis by Variable"))

#remove(BSky_Dataset_Overview)
#remove(BSky_Numerical_Statistics_Analysis )
```

In the above I requested the mean only `[mean=TRUE]`, but it supplies the mean & N & NAs,
How can I change this to only show the means?

Regards
Mark

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on the output in BlueSky Statistics, then select the export to Excel option. In Excel you can delete the rows you want to delete.

You can also try Data->Aggregate to output and select mean